# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Unity)

Tags: unity3d, null, objetos

Salvei meu projeto, fechei o `Unity` e depois que reabri o projeto, para minha surpresa, um erro foi apresentado no console:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object UIManager.SetUseable (ActionButton btn, IUseable useable)
>   (at C:/Users/Mystic Rabbit/Desktop/GameMaker/RPG
>   v9.1/RPG/Assets/Scripts/Managers/UIManager.cs:111) UIManager.Start ()
>   (at C:/Users/Mystic Rabbit/Desktop/GameMaker/RPG
>   v9.1/RPG/Assets/Scripts/Managers/UIManager.cs:53)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static UIManager instance;

    public static UIManager MyInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<UIManager>();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A reference to all the action buttos
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private ActionButton[] actionButtons;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject targetFrame;

    private Stat healthStat;

    [SerializeField]
    private Image portraitFrame;

    [SerializeField]
    private CanvasGroup keybindMenu;

    private GameObject[] keybindButtons;

    private void Awake()
    {
        keybindButtons = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Keybind");
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        healthStat = targetFrame.GetComponentInChildren<Stat>();

        SetUseable(actionButtons[0], SpellBook.MyInstance.GetSpell("Fireball"));
        SetUseable(actionButtons[1], SpellBook.MyInstance.GetSpell("Frostbolt"));
        SetUseable(actionButtons[2], SpellBook.MyInstance.GetSpell("Thunderbolt"));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            OpenCloseMenu();
        }

    }

    public void ShowTargetFrame(NPC target)
    {
        targetFrame.SetActive(true);

        healthStat.initialized(target.MyHealth.MyCurrentValue, target.MyHealth.MyMaxValue);

        portraitFrame.sprite = target.MyPortrait;

        target.healthChanged += new HealthChanged(UpdateTargetFrame);

        target.characterRemoved += new CharacterRemoved(HideTargetFrame);
    }

    public void HideTargetFrame()
    {
        targetFrame.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void UpdateTargetFrame(float health)
    {
        healthStat.MyCurrentValue = health;
    }

    public void OpenCloseMenu()
    {
        keybindMenu.alpha = keybindMenu.alpha > 0 ? 0 : 1;
        keybindMenu.blocksRaycasts = keybindMenu.blocksRaycasts == true ? false : true;
        Time.timeScale = Time.timeScale > 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public void UpdateKeyText(string key, KeyCode code)
    {
        Text tmp = Array.Find(keybindButtons, x => x.name == key).GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        tmp.text = code.ToString();
    }

    public void ClickActionButton(string buttonName)
    {
        Array.Find(actionButtons, x => x.gameObject.name == buttonName).MyButton.onClick.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetUseable(ActionButton btn, IUseable useable)
    {
        btn.MyButton.image.sprite = useable.MyIcon;
        btn.MyButton.image.color = Color.white;
        btn.MyUseable = useable;

    }
}
```

Estou deixando o link do youtube com os passos exatos do tutorial que estou tendo esse problema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5PJdhJ97uo

**Gravei um vídeo também fazendo os testes finais com resultados positivos, depois reiniciando o software e obtendo novos resultados negativos.**
https://youtu.be/kTabDddtjww

Lembre-se, eu fiz todo o tutorial 9.2 até o último segundo e consegui os mesmos resultados positivos que o professor. Apenas **depois** de reiniciar o software, esse erro apareceu no console.

Se eu apagar linhas **53 a 55** ou linhas **111 a 113**, o erro desaparece. É claro que as magias não estarão na barra de ação como no tutorial, mas o erro desaparece. O problema está acontecendo nessas linhas.

Fiz o tutorial 3 vezes, para ter certeza que não havia cometido algum erro no processo. O que eu acho estranho é que tudo funciona perfeitamente até **reiniciar o Unity.**

Answer (score 0):

Oi, verifique se você tem os `private ActionButton[] actionButtons;` setados no inspector do Unity3D! pois essa variável esta nula.

Quando a classe vai inicializar no método `Start` não há elementos na variável `ActionButton` e você as passa para o método `SetUseable` como null também, por isso o erro aparece em dois lugares no código.

Comment: Obrigado por responder! Aparentemente tudo no Unity está configurando corretamente: encurtador.com.br/vzZ17

Olhe esse vídeo que eu postei: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTabDddtjww&feature=youtu.be

Eu consigo fazer todas as magias funcionarem corretamente, porém após reiniciar o Unity, ele perde todas as referencias... Eu fiz 3 vezes o tutorial, metodicamente, passo a passo e sempre consigo configurar as skills, mas depois de reiniciar ele perde as referencias

Comment: Então quando você fecha a Unity perde os elementos setados em actionButtons isso? se sim tente abrir a Unity como administrador ou crie um prefab desta UI para que esses elementos não sejam reinicializados quando você abrir a Unity.